# Sparse matrix multiplication complexity

Tags: algorithm, matrix, complexity-theory, sparse-matrix, eigen

I want to express the computational complexity fo two algorithms: the sparse-matrix sparse-vector multiplication and the sparse-matrix sparse-matrix multiplication, as implemented in Eigen or Cusparse, using CSR representation.

I know that it depends on several parameters, especially the number of non-zero values in each elements.

However, I'm not able to find to find publications which details the complexity of such algorithms and expresses it using the O( ) notation.

Answer (score 8):

Say you are multiplying `A*B` with `A` a `m*k` matrix with `a` non-zeros per column, and `B` a `k*n` matrix with `b` non-zeros per column. Then, the number of operations (* and +) is:

```
2*n*b*a
```

because for each of the `n` columns of `B` we have to loop through the `b` columns of `A` for which the corresponding elements of `B` are non-zeros, and then multiply-accumulate the respective `a` non-zeros. If properly implemented, as in Eigen or Cusparse, we have three nested loops with exactly `n`, `b`, and `a` iterations, the complexity is thus `O(a*b*n)`.